# Send mouse clicks over a ten second countdown on socket.io client to node.js server and replay to user using redis stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, stream

Using node.js and socket.io send events such as mouse clicks on a ten second countdown. The mouse clicks would be sent over socket.io to a hash map on the node.js server and allow replay to the same client that produced the click events.

Client: HTML canvas when click sends the coordinates to the server. (index.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO click events and time</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom: 3rem;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
          Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      #messages {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #messages > li {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
      }
      #messages > li:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #efefef;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <progress value="0" max="10" id="progressBar"></progress>
    </div>
    <canvas
      width="160"
      height="200"
      id="canvas"
      style="background-color: lightblue;"
    ></canvas>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <p id="demo">Click me for Stream.</p>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        const url = window.location.origin;
        let socket = io.connect(url);
        var messages = document.getElementById("messages");

        document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

        function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "CLICKED!";
        }

        var clickCanvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");

        clickCanvas.addEventListener(
          "click",
          function (event) {
            var rect = clickCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
            var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
            console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
            socket.emit("mouse click", "x: " + x + " y: " + y);
          },
          false
        );

        socket.on("mouse click", function (msg) {
          var item = document.createElement("li");
          item.textContent = msg;
          messages.appendChild(item);
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });

        var timeleft = 10;
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
          if (timeleft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
          }
          document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 10 - timeleft;
          timeleft -= 1;
        }, 1000);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Server: Receives the mouse click coordinates and times via socket.io :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");

const server = http.Server(app).listen(8080);
const io = socketIo(server);
const clients = {};

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../client/"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../node_modules/"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html", { root: __dirname + "/../client" });
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("mouse click", (msg) => {
    var clickTime = new Date().getTime();
    io.emit("mouse click", msg + " " + clickTime);
  });
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected");
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ten second countdown"? Does the user have ten seconds to record mouse clicks, or does the page have to wait ten seconds before it starts replaying mouse clicks, or does the replay wait ten seconds between each mouse click, ...?

Comment: User has ten seconds to record mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Near the end of this video it shows how to replay a stream of events using redis and kaboom.js https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cowIZWASJNs. I'll post the code in the next few days.

```
 // Start a new stream for this game and set a long expiry in case 
  // the user abandons it.
  await redis.xadd(gameClicksKey, '*', 'event', 'start');
  redis.expire(gameClicksKey, 86400);
```

```
 const stream = redis.scanStream({
    match: 'kaboom:click:*'
  });

  const gameIds = [];

  stream.on('data', (keys) => {
    // Extract the gameId from the key and append to gameIds array.
    keys.forEach((key) => gameIds.push(key.split(':')[2]));
  });

  stream.on('end', () => {
    res.status(200).json({
      data: {
        gameIds,
        length: gameIds.length
      },
      status: 'success',
    })
  })
});
```